# Optimize the usage of CASE statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case, pivot-table

[image]

Hi all,

I have a table as shown in the screenshot above. I wrote a query using `CASE` statement so that it will return extra columns that I need. Below is the query that I wrote:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'class 1' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY student_id)) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS 'Class 1',
    CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'class 2' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY student_id)) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS 'Class 2',
    CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'class 3' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY student_id)) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS 'Class 3',
    CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'class 4' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY student_id)) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS 'Class 4'
FROM qa;
```

This is the result table that I get:

[image]

What I want to achieve in this query is, if the student attended the class, it will show `1` under the column of the class for all the rows belong to that student.

For example, student with `student_id` `2` attended `class 1`, so under `Class 1` column, both rows for `student_id` `2` will show `1`.

I already achieved what I want in my query, but right now instead of using `1`, I want it to be the `enrollment_date` of the class. Below is the final output that I want:

[image]

May I know how should I modify my query to get the final output in the screenshot above?

**2nd Question:**

As you can see in my query above, every class is having one `CASE` statement respectively in order to create the column for the class. However, there might be Class 5,6,7,... in future, so I need to add in the extra `CASE` statement again whenever there is different new class exist. Is there anyway that I can optimize my query so that there is no need to have 4 `CASE` statement for 4 different classes, and yet still can create columns for different classes (when there is a new class, there will be new column for the class as well)?

### Sample Data

```
create table qa(
    student_id INT,
    class varchar(20),
    class_end_date date,
    enrollment_date date
);

insert into qa (student_id, class, class_end_date, enrollment_date) 
values 
(1, 'class 1', '2022-03-03', '2022-02-14'),
(1, 'class 3', '2022-06-13', '2022-04-12'),
(1, 'class 4', '2022-07-03', '2022-06-19'),
(2, 'class 1', '2023-03-03', '2022-07-14'),
(2, 'class 2', '2022-08-03', '2022-07-17'),
(4, 'class 4', '2023-03-03', '2022-012-14'),
(4, 'class 2', '2022-04-03', '2022-03-21')
;
```

Comment: You need dynamic sql for your 2nd question. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html PS I might be more helpful if you published sample data as text https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach the sample data. I edited my question with query to create the sample table and data, thanks

Comment: Why do you want the duplicate rows? Surely you just want one row per student? I suggest you replace all images of data in your question with markdown tables.

Comment: It is not really duplicate rows, because the class_end_date are still different

Comment: Doesn't that rather defy the point in pivoting the enrolment date?

Comment: So actually my plan is, after having 4 columns with the enrollment date for each class , i will use these 4 columns minus the class_end_date column to find number of days between enrollment date for each class and class_end_date.

Comment: Maybe you have a better way to do it, but this is what I can think of so far, still new to MYSQL, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with both class_end_date and enrollment_date pivoted -

```
SELECT 
    student_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(class = 'class 1', enrollment_date, null)) 'Class 1 Enrolled',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(class = 'class 1', class_end_date, null)) 'Class 1 End',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(class = 'class 2', enrollment_date, null)) 'Class 2 Enrolled',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(class = 'class 2', class_end_date, null)) 'Class 2 End',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(class = 'class 3', enrollment_date, null)) 'Class 3 Enrolled',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(class = 'class 3', class_end_date, null)) 'Class 3 End',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(class = 'class 4', enrollment_date, null)) 'Class 4 Enrolled',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(class = 'class 4', class_end_date, null)) 'Class 4 End'
FROM qa
GROUP BY student_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

See  [*Pivot*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot) for a Stored Procedure that will generate and [optionally] run a query based on the table definition and data.